# Download excel file using angular 5 HttpClient Request

Tags: angular

I'm trying to download an excel file, using angular 5, httpClient Request. The fucntion that I'm using is:

```
getWithAttachement(url: string, filename: string) {

const httpOption: Object  = {
  observe:  'response',
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}),
  responseType: 'Blob'
};

return this.http.get(url, httpOption)
.map(res => {
  return {
    filename: filename,
    data: new Blob([res], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
  };
})
.subscribe(res => {
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(res.data, res.filename);
  } else {
    const link = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    a.href = link;
    a.download = res.filename;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link);
    a.remove();
  }
}, error => {
  console.log('download error:', JSON.stringify(error));
}, () => {
  console.log('Completed file download.');

});
  }
```

I am able to download the file, but unable to read its content. The error is:

Microsoft Excel
Excel cannot open the file 'SchedulingReport.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. OK